# Android ADV not working after I cleaned the code

Tags: android, sqlite, emulation

I got a weird problem. I just cleaned my code because after I have installed the Android Emmulator SQLite Database in Eclipse, every single line of my database got red line(errors) problems. I was running on the normal emulator for the SQLite testing. Before that I use my phone to run the programs.
So, I clean the code, change the build path( as eclipse suggest me to change it) now, I got this problems.
I try to do the HTC Sync but still not working !! :( pls help !

> [2012-04-07 12:51:09 - devilscan] Android Launch! [2012-04-07 12:51:09
>   - devilscan] adb is running normally. [2012-04-07 12:51:09 - devilscan] No Launcher activity found! [2012-04-07 12:51:09 -
>   devilscan] The launch will only sync the application package on the
>   device! [2012-04-07 12:51:09 - devilscan] Performing sync [2012-04-07
>   12:51:11 - devilscan] WARNING: Application does not specify an API
>   level requirement! [2012-04-07 12:51:11 - devilscan] Device API
>   version is 8 (Android 2.2.1) [2012-04-07 12:51:11 - devilscan]
>   Uploading devilscan.apk onto device 'HT08DPY02479' [2012-04-07
>   12:51:13 - devilscan] Installing devilscan.apk... [2012-04-07 12:51:29
>   - devilscan] Success! [2012-04-07 12:51:29 - devilscan] \devilscan\bin\devilscan.apk installed on device [2012-04-07 12:51:29
>   - devilscan] Done

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve the problem but now I have deleted the project (before that I copy all the codes somewhere) I create a new project and it is fine now ! :)

Thanks for those who kindly ans my question.